# Classic ASP - SQL Errors Stop Code, Never Show

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, vbscript

In 20 years of coding I have never come across this problem, and it has got me scratching my head to the point of insanity.

The platform in question is Windows 2016 Server (10.0.14393) with SQL Server 2017 on the Azure infrastructure. When I get a 'normal' ASP error, it shows the error just fine like so:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ea'
Syntax error
/tasks/DBTest.asp, line 4
Set Conn =
----------^
```

However, if the error is **in the SQL statement** or when trying to work with a value retrieved from it, it shows **nothing**. No error, no warning, zip. The SQL server I connect to has no relation to this fault - I connected to SQL 2017 as well as SQL 2012 (on a different machine where errors show just fine) - in both cases the same silence results. What's worse - the code just stops executing.

As you can imagine this is beyond frustrating when trying to debug or ascertain any kind of reason for failure. Of course all ASP error features are set correctly in IIS and as mentioned normal ASP errors show up just fine.

The issue seems to be that the moment the IIS server runs into an error originating from SQL it just stops all processing and makes no mention of the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the issue turned out to be that you can NOT have Server-side and client-side debugging **both** set to true. If you do this, very confusingly, client-side only shows simple ASP errors, and anything involving an object (not just SQL, but any!) will be hidden from view. Very logical eh...